# how to iterate on consecutive patterns only

Tags: python, regex

Given this semi-colon separated C/Java/other expression

```
text = "func(10+3,40+5);....;func(6+7,8+9)"
```

I want to extract the positions of the parameters of `func`, made of 2 added litterals.

```
import re
text = "func(10+3,40+5);....;func(6+7,8+9)"
result = [(x.start(),x.end()) for x in re.finditer("\d+\+\d+,?",text)]

print(result)
```

gives:

```
[(5, 10), (10, 14), (26, 30), (30, 33)]
```

But this isn't what I want: I would like to stop iterating when the parameters are not *consecutive* (because I'll look for the next `func` later, I want to extract parameters of `func`, not other functions).

In that case, `re.finditer` warps to the next pattern, skipping non-matching data in between.

To do what I want, I figured out a solution memorizing the previous match and checking if the current match comes right after it (if exist). Like this:

```
result=[]
previous_match = None
for x in re.finditer("\d+\+\d+,?",text):
    if previous_match and previous_match.end()!=x.start():
        break
    previous_match = x
    result.append((x.start(),x.end()))

print(result)
```

gives:

```
[(5, 10), (10, 14)]
```

which *is* what I want, but I lose the list comprehension, and I introduce an ugly memory parameter. Any better way to do this?

Comment: This is very easy with PyPi regex module. With `re`, you will have to rely on some additional code logic.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `text.partition(" ")[0]` then, would be faster. But this is code, and there can be _no_ spaces in theory. let me edit... wait there _has_ to be semicolons, so that could work.

Comment: @StefanPochmann not bad. I wanted a pure regex solution, but that could do.

Comment: could avoid the previous match variable using `zip(result, result[1:])`

Comment: @ArthurVaïsse how that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put my two cents in: wouldn't it be a lot easier with **two** regular expression?

```
import re

text = "func(10+3,40+5,1002+54);....;func(6+7,8+9)"

func = re.compile(r'func\([^()]+\)')
params = re.compile(r'\d+\+\d+,?')

result = [[p.group(0) for p in params.finditer(f.group(0))] for f in func.finditer(text)]
print(result)
# [['10+3,', '40+5,', '1002+54'], ['6+7,', '8+9']]
```

This way every element contains the parameter of only one function.

---

To have the positions, we need to add the outer start position as an offset:

```
import re

text = "func(10+3,40+5,1002+54);....;func(6+7,8+9)"

func = re.compile(r'func\([^()]+\)')
params = re.compile(r'\d+\+\d+,?')

result = [[(p.start() + f.start(), p.end() + f.start())
            for p in params.finditer(f.group(0))]
            for f in func.finditer(text)]
print(result)
# [[(5, 10), (10, 15), (15, 22)], [(34, 38), (38, 41)]]
```

Comment: nice start, but I need the _positions_ in the line (start/end) not the values. I'm sure you can transform your answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are regex engines that support a `\G` anchor which matches at the position of the last match, but python's `re` module does not.

A pure regex solution is possible if you use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which supports the `\G` anchor. Since `\G` only matches at the previous match or at the start of the string (but our first result does *not* occur at the start of the string), we use `\G(?:^func\()?\K` to match the `func(` at the start of the string and then discard it:

```
import regex

for match in regex.finditer(r'\G(?:^func\()?\K\d+\+\d+,?', text):
    print(match.span())
```

Otherwise you will have to resort to writing some python code. The easiest way is probably to search the string only up to the first ";" character:

```
import re

for match in re.finditer(r'\d+\+\d+,?', text[:text.find(';')]):
    print(match.span())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `iter` with the list?

```
import re
text = "func(10+3,40+5);....;func(6+7,8+9)"
result = iter([(x.start(),x.end()) for x in re.finditer("\d+\+\d+,?",text)])
```

Comment: err, it prints `<list_iterator object at 0x00000000033CB048>`. Using `next` on it issues the first value, but not the second one.

Comment: oh, soy you want to receive two items when you do a next?

Comment: exactly. The numerical parameters of the current `func`. Can be 1 or 2. I want all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As comments noted, it's not possible with the `re` module without extra logic (that I had figured out), so I would have to upgrade to the `regex` module.

Stefan provided an answer in comments which allows to keep using list comprehension because it doesn't require any flags. Stephan suggested using `str.split(" ")[0]` on the line to get rid of trailing functions, I prefered using `str.partition(";")[0]` since this is code so the function call *has* to end with `;` (and if it's at the next line, it doesn't matter)

```
result = [(x.start(),x.end()) for x in re.finditer("\d+\+\d+,?",text.partition(";")[0])]
```

As a bonus, `partition` is slightly faster than `split`, even if it creates 3 strings, which is slightly wasteful compared to a pure regex solution that doesn't create strings to throw them away.